# Getting a file from a file name passed in the command line (String[] args)

Tags: java, command, line

so I'm having an issue reading a file that is passed into my program through the command line. So, my program is called printFile. I do the following:

```
java printFile text1.txt
```

In my main, I have:

```
try{
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(args[0]);
  while(scan.hasNextLine())
  {
  System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
  }
 }
 catch(IOException e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

How can I correctly get the file passed in through the command line?

Comment: You get the file name via `args[0]`. But you should read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) about what that `Scanner` constructor does: it tokenizes the string itself; it doesn't treat that as a filename.

Comment: How do I read the text in the file thats in args[0] then? As in, how would I get the file path from just args[0]? But I see what youre saying.

Comment: You do something like create a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Is it possible to make a new file like this: 'File nFile=new File(args[0])' then make a new scanner object like: 'Scanner scan=new Scanner(nFile.getPath())' ? Or would it just be: ' scan=new Scanner(args[0].getPath())' ?

Comment: why not try it? :)

Comment: I'm using eclipse and I changed the run configurations to have text1.txt as a parameter, and I know it has text in it, yet it still is not printing anything when I use the Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));  Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner(String)` creates a scanner from the specified string. But you want to scan the content of a file, so you want to use the `Scanner(File)` constructor.

Change from this:

> ```
> Scanner scan=new Scanner(args[0]);
> ```

To this:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

Comment: But isn't this just making a new file with the same name, because args[0] is a string, not a file? Not reading the file param?

Comment: `File(String)` creates a Java `File` instance. That's not the same as creating a new file. It doesn't create a new file in the filesystem. Not at all. It creates a representation of the file in the filesystem at the specified path.